# Scikit-compatible network lasso implementation

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, lasso

Is anyone aware of a scikit-compatible network Lasso (nLasso) implementation?

These papers have source code as well:

> [D. Hallac, J. Leskovec, and S. Boyd, “Network lasso: Clustering and optimization in large graphs,” in Proc. SIGKDD, 2015, pp. 387–396.](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/network_lasso.pdf)

Code: https://riken-yamada.github.io/localizedlasso.html

> [[2] M.Yamada, T. Koh, T. Iwata, J. Shawe-Taylor, and S. Kaski, “Localized Lasso for High-Dimensional Regression,” in Proceedings of the 20th International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics, vol. 54. Fort Lauderdale, FL, USA: PMLR, Apr. 2017, pp. 325–333.](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v54/yamada17a/yamada17a.pdf)

Code: https://github.com/davidhallac/NetworkLasso

But these particular implementations are not very general and can't be used as a part of the pipelines.

I would like to use nLasso to do something like this (the example picked from [the scikit tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_boston.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-select-from-model-boston-py)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV

# Load the boston dataset.
boston = load_boston()
X, y = boston['data'], boston['target']

# We use the base estimator LassoCV since the L1 norm promotes sparsity of features.
clf = LassoCV(cv=5)

# Set a minimum threshold of 0.25
sfm = SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.25)
sfm.fit(X, y)
n_features = sfm.transform(X).shape[1]
```